# Nodejs hash of pdf files

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, sha256, cryptojs

I will hashing a pdf file using node js. But this code create same hash value for different pdf files.

```
function calculateHash(path) {
  let file_buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
  let sum = crypto.createHash('sha256');
  sum.update(file_buffer);
  const hex = sum.digest('hex');
  return hex;

}
```

exp path: __dirname + '/store/' + req.body.gkn + '/drive_doc.pdf'
How can I calculate hash of pdf file on js?

Comment: Are you sure the files you've tried with are different, to begin with?

Comment: yes, I am sure :(

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. The exact same code, when tried with `/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html` and `/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.pdf` (which I happen to have on my computer) do return different hashes.

Comment: Could my path be wrong?

Comment: It's possible, and it's really hard to say. I'd recommend maybe `console.log(path, hex)` within the function so you can see your code is doing what it should.

Comment: thank you very much, i will follow up with console.log.